# Create a subtype of Panel & style it with a template

Tags: 7, theming, entities, panels

So I'm trying to build a independent Landing Page for an event on our drupal 7 site. I would like to have the page contain a different main navigation menu then our site and also has the functionality of the content type "Panel".

I was Thinking to create a Content Type "Event" but how can I assign the Panel layout to it and how should I Assign that content type a specific menu?

The best solution would be to have a content type with the Fields:

- Event Name
- Panel Layout
- Top Navigation Menu
- ...

after creating that content type I would create a theme template for that type. The template would modify the top and bottom of the page but the center should still be modified as the same as a traditional panel.

Atm I don't know how to accomplish that :(

Would love to hear some feedback guys!

Answer (score 0):

when I have to create this type of "landing pages" I m usually following these steps.

#### 1/ The Layout.

Create a Panel Page. **Admin > Structure > Panel > New panel page**

1A/ If you want to get ride of header/footer region > there is an option for that.

1B/ If you want to keep these regions, but diplay other blocks, go to Admin > **Block > your block > Configure > Visibility settings > and setup the thing whith the page settings**.

#### 2/ Then your content.

What I'm usually doing here is depending on what you try to achieve, but if you are displaying only 1 event content, create a content type event is probably not the right approach.

But my point is, now you can create a page with what you want. So think about what you want to display (do you need a view of items ? do I need a block ? some blocks? do I need some beans ?) and architecture it as it was a standard page. Just prefix all you items type with one commun name, so you will be able to retrieve them later.

I hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to follow it. Do you have a idea what I can do to with my problem of the menu ?

Comment: Your menu is a block. You can define in which page you don't want your block as I explained with 1B.

Comment: I have now created a Panel page and a menu. I'm getting my main menu at template level (page.tpl.php), so I can't position the menu at the visibility settings. How should I make a template that recognize my new panel page?

Comment: You defined an url into your panel. So in your block setting, use that url to define if you want to display your block or not. I'm pretty sure i miss something on your build here.

Comment: I use foundation as a theme and I can only choose a main menu and a secondary menu at the theme settings. Those I call in my template. That's why I have problems with using the block visibility settings.